# Automapper map inside nested Enumerable properties

Tags: automapper

I would like to use automapper to map nested enumerable properties in existing enumerable nested properties.

Here is the problem simplify, i have Entities objects, they implement IEntity Interface, and Models objects, they implment IModel interfaces.

I would like to update easily and in a smart way IEntity object with IModel object

Example :

```
public class PersonEntity : IEntity 
{ 
    public int Id { get; set; } 
    public string Name { get; set }
    public IEnumerable<AddressEntity> Addresses { get; set }
}

public class AddressEntity : IEntity 
{ 
    public int Id { get; set; } 
    public string Street { get; set }
    public string entityField { get; set }
}

public class PersonModel : IModel 
{ 
    public int Id { get; set; } 
    public string Name { get; set }
    public IEnumerable<AddressModel> Addresses { get; set }
}

public class AddressModel : IModel 
{ 
    public int Id { get; set; } 
    public string Street { get; set }
}
```

If i have these two instance og PersonEntity and AddressEntity :

```
var personModel = new PersonModel() 
    {
        Id = 1,
        Name = "Name",
        Addresses = new List<AddressModel>() {
            new AdressModel() { Id =  1, Street = "Street B" }
        }


var person = new PersonEntity() 
    {
        Id = 1,
        Name = "Name",
        Addresses = new List<AddressEntity>() {
            new AdressEntity() { Id =  1, Street = "StreetA", EntityField  ="entityValue" }
        }
```

How can i map by Id, the Addresses element, to only erase the StreetA value by StreetB value, and keep existing entityField value intact ?

Thank you for help !

Comment: "keep existing entityField value intact". This would happen anyway as AddressModel doesn't have an entityField. It only maps what it can, and doesn't blow out other fields.

Comment: It will if i map like this : Mapper.Map<AddressModel, AddressEntity>(models, entities),  but if i map PersonModel into PersonEntity, it will create a new List<AddressEntity>, conaining an address entity : { Id =  1, Street = "Street B", EntityField  = null }, because automapper create new properties object of the mapping entity